# FHIR: Is it possible to persistently store Location information linked to a Patient resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir

In FHIR, the `Patient` resource contains an address field. However, if the patient is removed, the address is also discarded. Is there a way for location information to persist?

#### Context

We are developing a system for community health workers. CHWs visit homes periodically. They cover locations — and consequently, beneficiaries who reside in those locations. Hence, there is a need to be able to persistently store locations (beneficiary home addresses) in our system, and link them to current occupants (beneficiaries).

#### What I tried

The `Location` resource points to Organization. The only way it connects to a `Patient` resource is via an `Encounter`. This does not suffice.

Also, I also reviewed the `Group` resource, to try to connect a family or household (of  beneficiaries) to a Location. However, that too did not yield any results. My takeway was that `Group` could either group locations, or group patients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not something commonly done by most systems, so you won't likely find a 'core' element for it.  However, it's perfectly reasonable to do via an extension.  Simply define an [extension](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extensibility.html) on Patient with a type of Reference that refers to the Location record for the house/apartment building/whatever granularity you track.